# Getting extra lines on HTML source code when using function to generate the page in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm working on my assignment of PHP course.

The problem that I don't understand is that I'm keep getting extra lines when I actually use the function to all the parts.

Like on my `index.php` page

```
<?php include('library.php') ?>
<?php top_header(); ?>
```

And here is my function `top_header` codes from `library.php`

```
<?php function top_header(){ ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php } ?>
```

So when I use the validation the check my codes it says that the xml doctype has to be on the 1st line and when I check my source code I see that is not on the first line. I have remove and recreate the page two times now (first it was on the 4th line now it is 2nd line)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a line break between the first two lines:

```
<?php include('library.php') ?>
<?php top_header(); ?>
```

And this line break actually generates the first empty line!

Use the following:

```
<?php
    include('library.php');
    top_header();
?>
```

and everything works fine :-)

Comment: Yes I did clear the cache and open with another browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that somewhere in the library.php was echoing a return line.

Comment: I have my library.php codes above do you see any? please advice

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include('library.php') ?>` Must be outputting something. Check that.

Comment: the `library.php` codes is above do you think you can see and suggest please?

Comment: I don't understand can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline between those `<?php ?>` blocks:

```
<?php include('library.php') ?>
<?php top_header(); ?>
```

Remember that PHP outputs contents exactly in the places with PHP blocks. Rest remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're outputting HTML, you should't need:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

Second, when you break out of a `<?php ?>` code block, anything outside of the PHP tags will be outputted. So, you should get rid of all these exits / re-entries, as there could be whitespace there.

Third, you don't need a closing `?>`, as there is a possibility that there is a new-line / whitespace after that. So, omitting it is legal and saves you from making that mistake.

```
<?php function top_header(){
    // echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head><title></title></head>
<body>';
}
```

Comment: According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#normative), you don't need the XML declaration as it's optional, especially since you are specifying UTF-8.

Comment: Nobody ever said classes taught you the truth `:)`

Comment: haha @nickb, I know and the funny part now is that we should have start using HTML5 but old style of teaching :(

Comment: Did you try restructuring your function like I put in my post?

Comment: I did but it is the same. I'm going to use terminal to check if there is something going on maybe hidden space/characters.

Answer (score 0):

A typical cause for this: end-of-line characters after the closing tags. It may not even be obvious in the editor, but if you have carriage returns after the ?> in your code, the new lines can easily happen.

The easy remedy: just do not close the PHP tag. Nothing bad comes from it, and the superfluous line get eaten by the PHP interpreter.

This is, by the way, even worse if you have the empty lines being out out before your code, because you then have lost the ability to send out new headers. Funny hours of debugging, I can tell you :-)

Comment: Easy: do not put ?> into your files if they only contain PHP code.